# Find the element the user clicked inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, editor, wysiwyg

I am working on a HTML Editor using an `iframe`, I want users to be able to resize images once added. so when the user clicks on an image inside the `iframe` have a listener running. But all it gives me is the body tag rather than the element clicked. I have tried this many ways but none seem to work.

My code for this area is:

//site display is the iframe

//iframeBody is theid of bodyinside iframe

```
siteDisplay.document.getElementById('iframeBody').addEventListener("click", testForClicks, false); 


function testForClicks(){

 console.log(siteDisplay.document.activeElement);

 console.log(this);

 //both give me bodytag

}
```

I need to get the element clicked or the element highlighted

Any help would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the *highlighted* (or *active*) element you can use the `Selection`/[`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range) (link) API

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var firstNode = range.startContainer;
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Iframes are like separate windows opened inside your window. So,

```
iframe = document.getElementById('YourIframeId');
iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('innerIframeElementId').addEventListen......
```

This will work.
Also if you want to access the iframe window, go for:

```
iframe.contentWindow.
```

Hope this helps.